# Is it possible for a chrome extension to pass-through Windows Integrated Credentials?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Titles says it all, I want to know if it is possible to use Windows Integrated Credentials in order to pass the credentials to proxy authentication requests (which triggers onAuthRequested listener)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is onAuthRequested? Do you mean onAuthRequired in chrome.webRequest API? If so, it has asyncBlocking mode which you can utilize - 1. write a separate utility that runs in Windows and uses the integrated credentials, 2. communicate with the utility via nativeMessaging API, 3. invoke the async callback provided in onAuthRequired. This is as much as I can elaborate, see the documentation and demo extensions for more info.

Comment: yes I was referring to this event in the webRequest API. Thanks for the tip I'll try doing that !